# Dealing with Coordinates and curves

Tags: calculus

The curve is $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 5 - \frac{8}{x^2}$. The line $3y+x=17$ is the normal to the curve at a point $P$ on the curve. Given that the $x$-coordinate of $P$, is positive, what are the coordinates of $P$?

Comment: Can you check that my edit retains the same problem? I wasn't sure if it was $5 - \frac{8}{x^2}$ or $\frac{5-8}{x^2}$...

Comment: It is the same!

Comment: I personally don't quite understand the question, but I hope someone else can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The line $3y+x = 17$ has a slope of $-\dfrac{1}{3}$. Since that line is normal to the curve at point $P$, the tangent line must have a slope of $3$. Thus, $\left.\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right|_P = 3$. So, what must $x$ be?

Comment: so you set 3 = to 5- (8/x^2)? and solve for x?

Comment: Yes. Then, all you have to do is figure out what $y$ is.